# How To Fetch Data With Redux

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redux, mui-datatable

I have a trouble with fetch data with redux using `props.carlists`. I will use to pagination page with mui datatables. When i using fetch data the pagination is successfull. But when using props redux is didn't works.

I'm using reactjs and laravel with redux framework

This is my code:

```
    //const data = props.carlists;
    const loadData = (pages, rowsPerPages) => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        //fetch(`./indexListCar?page=${pages}&per_page=${rowsPerPages}`)
        props.carlists.(`page=${pages}&per_page=${rowsPerPages}`);
        .then((res) => {
          return res.json()
        })
        .then((resJson) => {
          setData(resJson.data)
          setCount(resJson.total)
          setIsLoading(false)
        })
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        loadData(page, rowsPerPage)
      }, [])
    const options = {
        filter: true,
        selectableRows: 'none',
        filterType: 'dropdown',
        responsive: 'vertical',
        rowsPerPage: 100,
        elevation: 0,
        onChangeRowsPerPage: false,
        setTableProps: () => {
            return {
                padding: '5px 3px 5px 10px',
                size: 'small'
            };
        },
        onRowSelectionChange: (i, t) => {
          console.log(i)
        },
        onTableChange: (action, tableState) => {
          switch (action) {
            case 'changePage':
              changePage(tableState.page, tableState.rowsPerPage);
              break;
            case 'sort':
              break;
            case 'changeRowsPerPage':
              changeRow(tableState.page, tableState.rowsPerPage)
              break;
            default:
          }
        }
    };
```

Please help me, and Thanks for answer :D

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work"? What are the error messages? What are you passing in the props? Please elaborate the question is too broad.

Comment: My data can't showing in page, cause i'm in studying with redux